# React fullcalendar error cannot read property 'seg' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I'm getting the titled error using react fullcalendar on mobile view only. When I'm in desktop view everything is working fine. The code is the below:

```
function CalendarPage() {
  const [currentEvents, setCurrentEvents] = useState(INITIAL_EVENTS);
  console.log(currentEvents);

  const handleDateSelect = (selectInfo) => {
    let title = prompt('Please enter a new title for your event');
    let calendarApi = selectInfo.view.calendar;

    calendarApi.unselect(); // clear date selection

    if (title) {
      calendarApi.addEvent({
        id: createEventId(),
        title,
        start: selectInfo.startStr,
        end: selectInfo.endStr,
        allDay: selectInfo.allDay
      });
    }
  };

  const handleEventClick = (clickInfo) => {
    clickInfo.event.remove();
  };

  const handleEvents = (events) => {
    setCurrentEvents({
      currentEvents: events
    });
  };

  function renderEventContent(eventInfo) {
    return (
      <>
        <b>{eventInfo.timeText}</b>
        <i>{eventInfo.event.title}</i>
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <FullCalendar
      plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
      headerToolbar={{
        left: 'prev,next,today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      }}
      initialView='dayGridMonth'
      locale={el}
      editable={true}
      selectable={true}
      selectMirror={true}
      dayMaxEvents={true}
      weekends={true}
      initialEvents={currentEvents}
      select={handleDateSelect}
      eventContent={renderEventContent}
      eventClick={handleEventClick}
      eventsSet={handleEvents}
    />
  );
}
```

I have read the documentation and the GitHub page but unfortunately didn't find a solution.

I have create a codesandbox to reproduce the error: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-microservice-obhup)

Comment: Did you end up solving this? Getting the same error now with the Vue component.

Comment: No, this is an open issue on the library https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-react/issues/96 I'm looking for another lib now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `contentHeight: 'auto'` to the configuration setup of the calendar. This happens on when the calendar renders on smaller sizes like mobile devices

Answer (score 1):

As Ivan Rossouw had mentioned you need to change contentHeight to auto in the FullCalendar configuration set up. Here is an example with props:

```
  render() {
return (
  <div className='demo-app'>
    {this.renderSidebar()}
    <div className='demo-app-main'>
      <FullCalendar
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
        headerToolbar={{
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        }}
        initialView='dayGridMonth'
        contentHeight='auto'
        editable={true}
        selectable={true}
        selectMirror={true}
        dayMaxEvents={true}
        weekends={this.state.weekendsVisible}
        events={this.state.currentEvents}
        select={this.handleDateSelect}
        eventContent={renderEventContent} // custom render function
        eventClick={this.handleEventClick}
        // eventsSet={this.handleEvents} // called after events are initialized/added/changed/removed
        /* you can update a remote database when these fire:
        eventAdd={function(){}}
        eventChange={function(){}}
        eventRemove={function(){}}
        */
      />
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

}